# Integrate a single AWS SDK JS for browser service with webpack and Typescript

Tags: webpack, aws-sdk-js

I have a Vue.js project, that I have integrated with Typescript and webpack. Everything is great. I am adding a simple SNS message service, so I integrated the AWS SDK. All seems well, but obviously, I do not want to bundle the entire AWS SDK if I am using a tiny sliver of it. I tried following all of the recommendations to no avail.

### Problem

I would like to be able to do the following:

`import { SNS } from 'aws-sdk/clients/sns';`

but I get an error

> ...node_modules/aws-sdk/clients/sns"' has no exported member 'SNS'.

### Interestingly...

`import { SNS } from 'aws-sdk'` works completely fine (but leaves me with a 5MB+ minified build file since it includes the entire sdk).

### I do have a workaround

I can use the AWS SDK builder tool, just download the SNS service, add that file to my directory tree, and import `SNS` from that file. That also works fine, and is my current best workaround. But now I am forced to maintain a file outside of npm, which is not great.

#### Any thoughts on where I am going wrong here?

---

#### Some extra info that might be helpful

Here is some  extra info that might be helpful.

My `ts.config.json` file looks like

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./inc/dist/ts-built/",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict":  true, 
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node"   
  },
  "include": [
    "./inc/src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"    
  ]
}
```

and the relevant part of my `webpack.config.js` file currently looks like

```
var path = require("path");
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    //context: path.resolve(__dirname, "./inc/src"),
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.vue', '.json'],
        alias: {
            'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
        }
    },
    entry: {
        main: './inc/src/search/main.ts'
    },
    output: {
        publicPath: '/inc/dist',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './inc/dist'),
        filename: '[name].build.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader',
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                options: {
                    appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/],
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                loader: 'json-loader'
            }
        ]
    }
};
```